# Meteor deploy - MAIL_URL not being set

Tags: meteor

I recently started deploying a meteor app off of my local machine and it seems that the MAIL_URL property is not being set when deploying to a *.meteor.com domain. No matter what I have tried the email is sent via the default MailGun

What I have tried so far.

1. Verified that process.MAIL_URL is set and works locally - ensures
   that I am setting MAIL_URL correctly
2. Verified that process.MAIL_URL
   is set on *.meteor.com domain by checking meteor logs - ensures that
   the process.env settings are being set on *.meteor.com
3. Tried multiple *.meteor.com domains - ensures it was not a subdomain specific
   issue
4. Tried multiple smtp providers: gmail and Mandrill - ensures
   that it was not an issue with the smtp provider
5. Tried creating a simple app with a simple test email button - ensures problem was not
   related to my app code

Nothing works. With the simple app, my code is the following:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to testmail.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      console.log("calling send mail");
      Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            'xxx@gmail.com',
            'xxx@domain.com',
            'Hello from Meteor!',
            'This is a test of Email.send.');           
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
// In your server code: define a method that the client can call
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      text: text
    });
  }
});
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://blahblah:token@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587/';      
    console.log(process.env);
  });
}
```

I am out of ideas at this point. Has anybody else experience this before and what was the resolution? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't mailgun work why do you want your own smtp server?

Comment: @Akshat yes mailgun works but I am using Mandrill for my app and figured *.meteor.com would be a good place to start testing with it until I ran into this issue.

Comment: Hey, you're token is showing.  Better to put the server code in a file in the server directory...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default meteor deploy can only use mailgun since you can't alter the environmental variables on meteor deploy hosting. Additionally meteor deploy hosting uses a galaxy configuration which takes precedence over environmental variables.

If you take a look at [[this file](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/ac8c1eb34ce54639e17ee8769dcd9f0a8e18000c/packages/application-configuration/config.js)] meteor deploy hosting uses some kind of App configuration that configures it over the environmental variable (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/email/email.js#L42). This is part of the galaxy configuration engine.

You have to modify the Email package to use a custom smtp server. To do this :

1. get the files from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/email and place them in a directory in your project `/packages/email`.
2. add this package to your meteor project with `meteor add email`. It should override the default meteor-core package. If it says already using, thats okay.
3. Modify /packages/email/email.js around [line 36](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/email#L36) to be:

   `var smtpPool = makePool("<YOUR CUSTOM MAIL_URL>");`

Then you should be good to go. Meteor should use this smtp host instead, even on meteor.com hosting.

Comment: First off I would have NEVER even begun to know where to look so thanks so much for this answer. I am confused though, are you saying that this is specific to *.meteor.com that the environment variables do not work because of the galaxy configuration? Because the documentation clearly (to me) states this is not the case.  It clearly says for meteor deploy "you may override this default by assigning to process.env.MAIL_URL before your first call to Email.send".. Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: I'm not too sure that part of the docs is right if you're getting this issue because the setting is set with `config.url || process.env.MAIL_URL` so the galaxy configuration will always override the env variable. It might be a good idea to open up an issue on github about this

Comment: ok, thanks for this. I need to step away from the computer for a bit because my head is going to explode but will look into this some more once I have recuperated.

Comment: Also yes it looks like on meteor deploy the galaxy configuration is used instead of environmental variables. Looking at the history its also a more recent change, they've not updated the docs

Comment: I see you submitted here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1647. This provided workaround works, thanks again. I will be able to test out smtp on meteor.com now.