# How to send verification email using userAccounts,accounts-password in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to set up email verification once the user is registered in my app but I receive "Internal Server Error"

Here is my code to create signup form

```
 <template name="LoginModal">

    {{#if $not currentUser }}

        {{> atForm}}



   {{/if}}
  </template>
//code inside the client folder to configure email verification
   AccountsTemplates.configure({
   confirmPassword:false,
   termsUrl:'terms-of-use',
   privacyUrl:'privacy',
   sendVerificationEmail: true,
   enforceEmailVerification:true,

  forbidClientAccountCreation: true

  });

//Here is my route to load the signup form
 Router.route('/admin/addUser',{

     action: function () {
    BlazeLayout.render('master_layout',       
     {body:'LoginModal',dashboard:'UserDashboard',pageHeader:'AddUserHeader'});
  }
});
 //No any other routes for sign up has been configured.
```

//The error I receive

```
(Mail not sent; to enable sending, set the MAIL_URL environment variable.)
I20170311-20:56:01.885(5.5)? MIME-Version: 1.0
I20170311-20:56:01.886(5.5)? Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2017 15:26:01 +0000
 I20170311-20:56:01.887(5.5)? From: "Meteor Accounts" <no-reply@meteor.com>
```

How can I set up this to send an email to the created user's email.Where should I write the sender's email address?

Comment: the code you posted seems fine.. can you show your code of how you are configuring the routes? try commenting out stuff to see when the issue goes away. [This projcet](https://github.com/meteor/todos) is using AccountsTemplates if you want to compare to it.

Comment: I am currently outdoor.I will post the code as soon as I get home.Isn't it necessary to include the sender's email adress somewhere in the code?.I haven't done it anywhere So I'm wondering how tge email is sent...

Comment: AccountsTemplates handles all of that. What you need is a url, else it will print the email on the server log (terminal).

Comment: @mutdmour Thanks..I edited my question with the route code.Hope you find the errors.

Comment: I did some changes in the code.Now a new error is shown. I added it in the question.How can I set the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables)

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://postmaster%40meteorize.mailgun.org:YOURPASSWORD@smtp.mailgun.org:587';
});
```

Comment: I copied the code and pasted in a file in server folder.Then I tried to register a user.Then I received this error "Exception while invoking method 'ATCreateUserServer' AuthError: Invalid login - 535 5.7.0 Mailgun is not loving your login or password"

Comment: This is the "From" address when you get an email. Did you signup for mailgun? This url is for a developer with an account on mailgun. [Here's how you can do the same with gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438118/sending-email-using-gmail-smtp-meteorjs)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks.My gmail is dileka.14@cse.mrt.ac.lk.  I can't figure out the username to fill in..

Comment: I signed up in mailgun and that worked.Thanks for your advice.